# What is meant by value types in the context of JS?

Tags: javascript

What is meant if people speak of **value types** in the context of JavaScript? I'm coming from a Java/C/C++ background, and never heard this term before. Are *Number*, *String*, *undefined*, *null* and *Boolean* value types?

Comment: Most likely they meant "data types", but for example C# does have "value types", so it is a bit confusing. Can you give a little more context?

Answer (score 3):

I guess so. They're called `datatypes`, just like any other programming language. Naturally, if a variable has a type, so does the value.

Answer (score 3):

In some other languages the term "value type" contrasts with "reference type", where generally assignments of value types involves copying the actual value, while assignment of reference types means copying the pointer (related to this you may have heard the terms "pass by value" and "pass by reference" when talking about function parameters). More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type

JavaScript has this value versus reference concept too, but I don't think that's what they meant in the [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> Algorithms within this specification *manipulate values each of which has an associated type. The possible 
>   value types are* exactly those defined in this clause. Types are further subclassified into ECMAScript language 
>   types and specification types.
>   An ECMAScript language type corresponds to values that are directly manipulated by an ECMAScript 
>   programmer using the ECMAScript language. The ECMAScript language types are Undefined, Null, Boolean, 
>   String, Number, and Object.

As you can see in the bit I italicized, they were talking about manipulating "values" and then went on to talk about what "types" those values might have. In my opinion this is more a case of poor wording where what they meant was "the possible types of values are"...

As far as what the people you are talking about when you say "if people speak of value types", I think we'd need more context to be sure...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as well as some others. See section 8 of [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I think that they mean `string`, `number`, `boolean` and `undefined` because when you assign them to another variable, you copy the value, not a pointer.

```
var a = 'abc';
var b = a;
a = 'def';
// b === 'abc'

var a = { b: 'abc' };
var b = a;
a.b = 'def';
// b.b === 'def'
```